# SwiftUI, How to stop GridItem from expanding

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am following the course CS193p from Stanford, since im learning swift on my own and all the course material has been released (I am not enrolled).

Im currently working on the midterm projekt in which i have to develop the game "Set".

The cards should be displayed adaptively on the screen so that the cards get smaller or bigger when cards are added or removed to the board. The professor has released a struct which is supposed to handle this. (This works)

One of the requirements for the assignment is that all the cards should be equally sized. And this is where i am stuck. The cards with 3 shapes on them are overflowing into the other cards:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXKZ8.png)

Here is the code:

```
struct AspectVGrid<Item, ItemView>: View where ItemView: View, Item: Identifiable {
    var items: [Item]
    var aspectRatio: CGFloat
    var content: (Item) -> ItemView
    
    init(items: [Item], aspectRatio: CGFloat, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Item) -> ItemView) {
        self.items = items
        self.aspectRatio = aspectRatio
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                VStack {
                    let width: CGFloat = widthThatFits(itemCount: items.count, in: geometry.size, itemAspectRatio: aspectRatio)
                    LazyVGrid(columns: [adaptiveGridItem(width: width)], spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach(items) { item in
                            content(item).aspectRatio(aspectRatio, contentMode: .fit)
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer(minLength: 0)
                }
            }
        }
    
    private func adaptiveGridItem(width: CGFloat) -> GridItem {
        var gridItem = GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: width))
        gridItem.spacing = 0
        return gridItem
    }
    
    private func widthThatFits(itemCount: Int, in size: CGSize, itemAspectRatio: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        var columnCount = 1
        var rowCount = itemCount
        repeat {
            let itemWidth = size.width / CGFloat(columnCount)
            let itemHeight = itemWidth / itemAspectRatio
            if  CGFloat(rowCount) * itemHeight < size.height {
                break
            }
            columnCount += 1
            rowCount = (itemCount + (columnCount - 1)) / columnCount
        } while columnCount < itemCount
        if columnCount > itemCount {
            columnCount = itemCount
        }
        return floor(size.width / CGFloat(columnCount))
    }
    
}
```

I have tried using .scaleToFit, .frame, and changing diffrent sizes across the struct but nothing have worked so far.

Using .clipped is the closest i got since all elements now are the same size, except for the fact that the bottom of the blue card gets cut off.

I know i have to fix the height of the GridItem somehow but i cant figure it out.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

CardView() code:

```
struct CardView: View {
let card: Model.Card

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ZStack{
            let shape = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
            if !card.isMatched {
                shape.fill().foregroundColor(.white)
                shape.strokeBorder(lineWidth: 4).foregroundColor(card.isSelected ? .red : .blue)
            //} else if card.isMatched {
            //    shape.opacity(0)
            //} else {
            //    shape.fill()
            }
            VStack {
                Spacer(minLength: 0)
                ForEach(0..<card.numberOfShapes) { index in
                    cardShape().frame(height: geometry.size.height/5)
                }
                Spacer(minLength: 0)
            }.padding()
            .foregroundColor(setColor())
            .aspectRatio(CGFloat(6.0/8.0), contentMode: .fit)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I briefly looked at Paul Hegarty's lecture, and I think that you problem may not be with the `AspectVGrid`. `AspectVGrid` does not change the size of the views it contains. They are already supposed to be a certain aspect ratio that is passed in to `AspectVGrid`. I think the issue is with you `CardView()` not returning a view that is always a certain aspect ratio. Can you post your `CardView()` code?

Comment: Thanks man i was able to fix it now by doing  `.frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)` after `.aspectRatio` , is this the right way to do it?

Comment: That would make sense. One thing to remember with regard to view modifiers is that order can be VERY important. Just because it didn't work one way, doesn't mean that the modifier isn't the answer. Case in point: A lot of questions come up with regard to `Image` where the size won't change. However, you need to use `.resizeable` first, otherwise the `Image` ignores the other modifiers.

Comment: Also, when asking questions, make sure you include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Leaving out part of the code means we can't run it, I experiment. Even if it is just a mock up of you actual code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will do that next time.